# How do I keep the text from changing color when a link in html in a webview is clicked? (Android)

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

I have almost no experience with html and am only using a WebView to load a local Word doc converted to html that serves as the FAQ in my app. Items in the table of contents can be clicked to jump to a FAQ item.

Currently the table of contents links turn purple when they've been clicked. Can I turn off this behavior so that the links stay blue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If web view is navigating to website that you own, then you can change its CSS like

```
a:visited{
   color : #0000FF;
}
```

else you can't change its color.